# Wait for multiple images to load

Tags: vue.js

I have multiples images to load, and i put them in an Array.

In a loop, i increment a counter when an image is loaded.

When this counter is equal to the Array length of my images, i want to remove the loading indicator.

i dont know why, thats doesnt work.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  created() {
    let imageLoaded = 0;
    for (const imageSrc of this.imagesToPreload) {
      if (imageLoaded === this.imagesToPreload.length) {
        console.log("Done !");
        this.loading = false;
      }

      const img = new Image();
      img.src = imageSrc;

      img.onload = () => {
        imageLoaded++;
        console.log(imageLoaded);
      };
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: true,
      imagesToPreload: [
        "https://placeimg.com/1280/800/any",
        "https://placeimg.com/1280/800/any",
        "https://placeimg.com/1280/800/any"
      ]
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <div v-if="isLoading">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the variable is isLoading, and you are setting to false the variable "loading"... please indent the code better

Comment: Sorry for the bad indentation, i have updated my post. Thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code will check if the images are loaded **immediately** after setting the image sources. It won't wait until any of the images are actually loaded.

In my opinion, the best way would be to use promises:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  created() {
    const images = this.imagesToPreload.map(imageSrc => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = imageSrc;
        img.onload = resolve;
        img.onerror = reject;
      });
    });

    Promise.all(images).then(() => { 
      console.log("Images loaded!");
      this.isLoading = false;
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error("Some image(s) failed loading!");
      console.error(error.message)
    });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: true,
      imagesToPreload: [
        "https://placeimg.com/1280/800/any",
        "https://placeimg.com/1280/800/any",
        "https://placeimg.com/1280/800/any"
      ]
    };
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
     <div v-if="isLoading">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

Or, try putting a check in the `onload` callback for each image.

```js
  created() {
    let imageLoaded = 0;
    for (const imageSrc of this.imagesToPreload) {    
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = imageSrc;

      img.onload = () => {
        imageLoaded++;

        if (imageLoaded === this.imagesToPreload.length) {
          console.log("Done !");
          this.isLoading = false;
        }

        console.log(imageLoaded);
      };
    }
  }
```