# Uncaught Error: Incomplete or corrupt PNG file

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, jspdf

I am trying to add a couple of images to a pdf. I am using the `jspdf` plugin for this. My code is as following:

```
document.getElementById("help").addEventListener("click",function(){
    var base1="";
    var base2="";
    var base3="";
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var img=new Image();
    var img1=new Image();
    var img2=new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        base1 = canvas.toDataURL();
    }
    img.src='/Screenshot (1).png';
    img1.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
        base2 = canvas.toDataURL();
    }
    img1.src='/Screenshot (2).png';
    img2.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
        base3 = canvas.toDataURL();
    }
    img2.src='/Screenshot (3).png';

    doc.addImage(base1,'PNG',20,36,100,120);
    
    doc.addImage(base2,'PNG',20,158,100,120);
   
    doc.addImage(base3,'PNG',20,281,100,120);
    doc.save("example.pdf");
})
```

But when I execute the code, I get the following error in `addImage()`:

> Uncaught Error: Incomplete or corrupt PNG file

How do I fix this?

**EDIT:** After implementing @AKX's solution, the code works in the local machine. But when tested live, it throws this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'error', target:
> null, currentTarget: null, eventPhase: 0, …}

Comment: You're not waiting for the images to load before you create a PDF.

Comment: then should I use a `setTimeout()` function before `doc.addImage`?

Comment: A `setTimeout()` is not robust (unless you make it infinitely long, in which case it's quite useless).

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/k6owv9ya/ (untested!) also: [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: Duplicate: [Wait for multiple images to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53707345/wait-for-multiple-images-to-load)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not waiting for all the images to load. You can refactor things to use [a promisified function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to load an image and turn it into a data URI ([though according to the docs for jspdf, a HTMLImageElement would also do, so you could skip the canvas bit](https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/module-addImage.html)), and then turn your handler into an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to make it easy to just `await` for all the loads.

```
function loadImageAsDataURL(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      resolve(canvas.toDataURL());
    }
    img.onerror = reject;
    img.src = url;
  });
}

document.getElementById('help').addEventListener('click', async function () {
  // Load all images first...
  var base1 = await loadImageAsDataURL("/Screenshot (1).png");
  var base2 = await loadImageAsDataURL("/Screenshot (2).png");
  var base3 = await loadImageAsDataURL("/Screenshot (3).png");
  // ... and then generate the PDF.
  var doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.addImage(base1, 'PNG', 20, 36, 100, 120);
  doc.addImage(base2, 'PNG', 20, 158, 100, 120);
  doc.addImage(base3, 'PNG', 20, 281, 100, 120);
  doc.save('example.pdf');
})
```

Comment: This is predictably a dupe, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53707345/wait-for-multiple-images-to-load

Comment: It works in `localhost`, but I keep getting an `Uncaught (in promise)` error, after uploading it live

Comment: Well, do those paths exist in your live environment? You'd get an error if they don't.

Comment: Yes they exist. The file hierarchy is the same as the `localhost` one

Comment: See your browser's network inspector to figure out what the error might be.

Comment: Ok, after renaming all the image names, the code's finally working. For some weird reason, it wasn't accepting the `(`,`)`,`_` special characters.